# SQLite referencing another table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I currently have a table that stores color by ID (auto increments), string color name, stringrgb, string hex and string hsv.
Is it possible to have another table that has it's own ID, string palette name, and then reference multiple colors from the first table for a single ID/palette name? I know arrays aren't supported in sqlite so I'm not sure how to constantly add new columns as I'm saving on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want a many-to-many relationship between your two tables. This would require you to Make a third tablet  which stores two foreign Keys, one is the primairy key of your color tablet, the other the is of pallete. Of one pallete needs thee colors for example, you Just inserts three  key pairs.